# get sender in href javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have an anchor with a href tag of `javascript:someFunc()`. How can I get the tag that called the javascript code? in the `onclick` attribute i know you can pass `this`, but `this` references the `DOMWindow` when called from the href tag. I HAVE to use the href tag as the code i'm working with limits me to using it only. Anyone have an idea on what I can do?

Comment: Why don't you put an ID on the link and pass the ID in the function. Then you can use `document.getElementById(THE ID PASSED)`...

Comment: can't. I can't add any attributes. I'm only allowed to specify the href tag and the anchor's innerHTML

Comment: Can you paste the piece of code here please?

Comment: I just found out that the code I'm working with (SMF) does automatically provide an ID. However, I'm still curious as to if it is possible with JUST using code inside the href tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. The only way you can reference to the href is this:

`<a href="# OR SOME VALID URL" onclick="YOURFUCNTION(this);"> Click Here </a>`